# Disable a particular keypress event in content editable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, css

i have a content editable div, i want to disable the undo operation i.e control + z operation on the editable div, i tried like this

```
  //key up handles all keypresse events. Backspace wont fire for simple keypress event in jquery
        $("#Partner").keyup(function (e) {

            if (e.keyCode == 90) {
                e.preventDefault();
                return;
            }
```

still i am able to perfrom undo operation, any input on how to disable undo on editable div?

Comment: why do you want to do this?

Comment: sharepoint edit control does not allow user to make undo, we need same one in our aps so

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution

```
    $("#Partner").keydown(function (e) {

        if (e.keyCode == 90 && e.ctrlKey) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return;
        }
    });

    //key up handles all keypresse events. Backspace wont fire for simple keypress event in jquery
    $("#Partner").keyup(function (e) {

        if (e.keyCode == 90 && e.ctrlKey) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$("#Partner").bind("keydown", function (e) {
       if (e.keyCode == 90 && e.ctrlKey) {
           e.preventDefault();
           return;
      }
}
```

**Note:** the key operations are performed in the keydown operation also. so try to prevent the keydown event to block the default behavior.

Comment: i got solution, we need to handle both keydown and keyup